# c# Access to the path denied on ubuntu 18.04 server

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, server, discord.net

My friend and I wanted to make a discord server. I made the bot in c# and needed something to host it on so it can run 24/7, I've chosen Digitalocean. I created a ubuntu 18.04 droplet, installed dotnet sdk on it and cloned my github bot repo (Not the best solution, I know). But when I tried to do `dotnet run`, I got the "Access to path the path ' ' is denied" Error. I got the same error when i tried it using docker on ubuntu 16.04. Can anyone help me with this problem? (It worked fine on windows 10)

Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
WORKDIR /app

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# copy and build everything else
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "out/Bot.dll"]
```

the error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path '/app/out' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
   at Bot.Program.MainAsync() in /app/Program.cs:line 38
   at Bot.Program.Main(String[] args) in /app/Program.cs:line 16
```

chmod -x and chmod -R 777 didn't work

Comment: What path is it stored in? What specifically throws the error, is the program looking for a path, or is the `dotnet run` command failing?

Comment: You need to do `chmod +x FILETHATNEEDSACCESSTO` In order to give it execution rights. At least I had this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to make a release publish for ubuntu, give permission for execution with `chmod -R 777 PATHTOPUBLISHFOLDER` and then running it with `path to the file without extension in the publish folder`